# Struts 2 action tag on GAE issue

Tags: java, google-app-engine, struts2, tags, struts-action

I have a problem with struts 2 action tag on GAE.
When I try

`<s:action name="User_info" namespace="/" executeResult="true" />`

i get following error

`"com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger error: Could not execute action: //User_info java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:"`

On local everything works fine...
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was within the action itself not in the Struts 2. I used JDO but forgot to include jar fiels in lib folder.
My mistake, Sorry.